# Your Open Graph story did not publish on any of the configured platforms

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a web app that I'm trying to get in the Facebook App Center. After submitting it, I'm getting the following warning:

> Your Open Graph story did not publish on any of the configured platforms. Update with more detailed usage instructions that indicate how to trigger and publish the action for all configured platforms.

The only action I implement is the like create action.

I've Googled this message, and not found any helpful answers, and this message has no specific information on what the problem is or how to resolve it.  Any insights would be most appreciated.

(screen shot)
[image]

Comment: Can you post some full screen screenshot where you are getting this warning

Comment: I've added the screen showing the error - I get to this by clicking the "Like" action type under the Open Graph section of the Developer Dashboard, which has a red dot denoting an error.

Comment: The error is quite straight I guess- have you shown them the steps to publish the story via your app? And your testers are able to publish the story successfuly?